# Can I combine archive template's Jquery sort by/view per page events so that they dont reset each other?

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am Using Jquery to let visitors modify the query order and per page amount on an archive page. There bar at the top of the archive list looks like this:

> **sort by** `title/date/poularity` **see per page**  `'all/20'` (and if applicable display the pagination).

full working function and template tag I have so far at: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bd3fnA2Q)

It all works great BUT currently the two events are resetting each other - meaning I can change the amount or I can change the order but I can't have the amt and sorting work at the same time.  Am I going to complicated with this? Is there an easier way to combine the two?

```
$('.amt-button').click(function(){
    var a_str = $(this).text();
window.location.href = "?a="+a_str;
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});

$('.sorter-dropdown').change(function(){
var o_str = $(this).val();
window.location.href = "?o="+o_str; 
$(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

As you can see above they are getting called by different events - button click and select change - but I was wondering if I can somehow get the value of the 'a' or 'o' if it was already set and called in the other event so that they can both be applied ?

Also the class highlight gets reset after the event reloads the query- kind of rendering it useless as well - because I wanted to visually highlight the 'current' sort & amt button/options for the user. is there way to make the highlight class still be applied after the new query reloads the page?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: I figured out how to combine the two events - I had to get the values out of the address bar (http://pastebin.com/Pp4QhgAf)- However still cant figure out how to keep the highlight on current - will tackle that tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, Mel. I'm sorry to say, but this is off-topic. I'll flag, so a moderator can move it to SO (this avoids asking the same Q 2 times).

Answer (score 0):

I have answered part 1 of my original question (how to make it so the two events don't cancel themselves out) It involved getting and stripping the variable from the url - which I then used with an if else statement to say if it was undefined use a default value in address, and if it was already set in the url pass that value on.

This is what the 'sortbar' looks like so far (and it works!):
[how sort bar looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h3vG.png)

The full function  (still a bit messy) [Paste bin full code](http://pastebin.com/Q5mvxWem)

I am still having trouble with applying a highlight class to the current buttons/options. My logic so far is to make a function that runs with window load and retrieves the variable from the url - then checks if there is a button that has an equal value - and if so applies class to that said button. However I think I am missing some key pieces to get there:

```
`// trying to make highlight style carry over. 
$(window).load(function(){
    // get the amt per value from url set it as amt_highlight var
    var amt_highlight = $.getUrlVar('amt_per');
    // if a button with class.amount-buttons value is equal to amt_highlight
    if ( $('.amt-button').val(); == amt_highlight){
    // then add class to that button
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
    }       
});`
```

Does anyone have any insights on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question again (part2 about making the buttons and options have a current class) I believe they were both related enough to be in one question because they both were about how to get the var values in the url to use them within the same overall function - but this was my first post in this site - so maybe I misunderstood. What I finally worked out:

```
$(".amt-button").addClass(function(index) {
var addedClass;
var amt_current = $.getUrlVar('amt_per');
var amt_val = $(this).val();
if ( amt_val  == amt_current ) {
  addedClass = "current";
}
return addedClass;
});
```

To explain: the addclass function calls the buttons with the amt-button class - and if their value is equal to the var value stripped from the url - the class 'current' is added to the 'current' button in question. Good for having control of how the buttons render for the user. hopefully this helps someone if they were struggling with it as I was.